# I am sailing song - Rod Stewart

Tags: remix, musicals

Is there a Remix of the classic song "I am Sailing" sung by Rod Stewart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can find multiple by [searching the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sailing+rod+stewart+remix&t=braveed&ia=web).